# Typescript Type of a dictionary and a list

Tags: typescript, types

What's the difference between the codes below about defining a type of props

I found out the first one didn't give me a type error, but i don't know why the second code I had written first was wrong. For me, it seems like pretty make sense.

```js
type Props = {
  reason: {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    reference?: 
      {
        title: string;
        link: string;
      }[];
  };
};
```

#### and

```js
type Props = {
  reason: {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    reference?: [
      {
        title: string;
        link: string;
      }
    ];
  };
};
```

Comment: "I don't know why the second code I had written first was wrong."  How do you know it was "wrong"?  I don't see where you're describing an actual problem or error anywhere.  Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is the type of the `reference` property. In the first `Props` the `reference` is an array of

```
{
   title: string;
   link: string;
}
```

However, in the second `Props` you define a tuple, not an array, which means that it contains only 1 element

Comment: The reason for *what* error?  I don't see an error anywhere.

Comment: I see. Adding [] tells it is an array.